# How to BATCH remux combine video and audio to one file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv, android

#### How can BATCH remux video and audio to one file?

I'm trying this on mine android termux.
So what I'm trying:

1. I want to rip audio from video and convert to wav. **ffmpeg -i inp.mkv -map 0:1 audio.wav**
2. Extract only video. **mkvextract tracks "inp.mkv" 0:video.mkv**
3. Remux Combine extracted video and wav audio file. **mkvmerge -o final.mkv video.mkv audio.wav**

## UPDATE

I Have found the command Solved myself

> for f in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:1 "${f%mkv}wav";done && for i in *.mkv; do mkdir -p "${i%.*}" && mkvmerge -o "${i%.*}/${i%.*}.mkv" -A "$i" "${i%.*}.wav"; done

## Another Question

How can I batch convert ssa to srt and send it to folder and also give subtitle the same name as video?

for f in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:1 "${f%mkv}wav";done && for i in *.mkv; do mkdir -p "${i%.*}" && mkvmerge -o "${i%.*}/${i%.*}.mkv" -A "$i" "${i%.*}.wav"; done && for f in *.ass;do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%ass}srt";done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for f in .mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:1 "${f%mkv}wav";done && for i in .mkv; do mkdir -p "${i%.}" && mkvmerge -o "${i%.}/${i%.}.mkv" -A "$i" "${i%.}.wav"; done